# check user is logged in to opencart or not

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am new to opencart. I have installed opencart on my domain

```
http://example.org/ocart
```

and a php application at url

```
http://example.com/testapp
```

`testapp` is a basic php application in which I want to check if any user is logged in to `opencart` or not. Is it possible to check in php app that any user is logged in to opencart and if it is logged in then can we get the email id of logged in user.

Both `ocart` and `testapp` are using the same database.

Comment: I don't know opencart but most applications would set a session variable to indicate a login session is active. If you're trying to query that from another session you might have difficult. Really it's none of your business if another user is logged in. If the app writes some info to the database about who has logged in and when, you could use that. It won't be real-time info, but not sure why you'd need that anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You can check your other question you will get your answer

[access session data of opencart through php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362992/access-session-data-of-opencart-through-php-file)

After doing above steps you can access in other `http://example.com/testapp`

Just Access with this code

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['opencart']['customer_id'])){
      // User Loged in.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the controller, ask if he is logged in and add the block, or combine it with other parameters desirable for the query.

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
 // your code here, if he is logged in
}
```