# access session data of opencart through php file

Tags: php, session, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am new to opencart. I have my basic php code at `http://localhost/testphp`

and my opencart is installed at `http://localhost/opencart`. What I want to do is that in `testphp`, I have a page in which I `want to check that if any user is logged in or not at opencart`.

If it is logged in then I want to perform x function

and It not logged in then want to perform y function

I have tried to logged in to opencart and tried to `print_r($_SESSION)` in testphp.
 It is returning blank. How can I perform this ? Please help me

Comment: There is a `customer_online` table in OpenCart database. see `getCustomersOnline` function in `admin\model\report\customer.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are using localhost then you can try this.**
or same hosting account or cpanel

**Go to catalog/controller/common/header.php**

Before **"public function index() {"**
  Add this code

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index() {    
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['opencart'] = $this->session->data;
```

You Have to Print Array in  `http://localhost/testphp` 
Code :

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Your Output Will be

```
Array
(
    [opencart] => Array
        (
            [language] => en-gb
            [currency] => USD
            [customer_id] => 2
            [shipping_address] => Array
                (
                    [address_id] => 2
                    [firstname] => Prashant
                    [lastname] => Bhagat
                    [company] => 
                    [address_1] => Surat
                    [address_2] => 
                    [postcode] => 395003
                    [city] => Surat
                    [zone_id] => 1485
                    [zone] => Gujarat
                    [zone_code] => GU
                    [country_id] => 99
                    [country] => India
                    [iso_code_2] => IN
                    [iso_code_3] => IND
                    [address_format] => 
                    [custom_field] => 
                )

        )

)
```