# How to check if user is logged in opencart version 3.x

Tags: php, session, opencart, opencart-3

I'm using OpenCart 3.0.3.2

I want to check if the user is logged in or not in a file called `test.php` located outside opencart folder.
for example, if the shop URL is http://www.example.com/shop
then the PHP file to check is in http://www.example.com/test.php

I saw in this link someone is asking the same question before 2 years.
[check user is logged in to opencart or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354618/check-user-is-logged-in-to-opencart-or-not)

This was for version `2.x`, and when I try it did not work.
So how to do it in version `3.0.3.2`?

I have tried different things with the session but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested both those answers combined. Works perfect. Check the following:

1. Both OpenCart and test.php should be on the same domain and same server. Folder on the level higher than OpenCart root is OK, because we are working with PHP `$_SESSION`.
2. Firstly user have to go to OpenCart and log in (or not) so the session will receive new data.

Lets collect all that solutions together. Open from your OpenCart 3 root *catalog/controller/common/header.php* and find

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index() {
```

add below

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['opencart'] = $this->session->data;
```

Now go to your *test.php* and add

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['opencart']['customer_id'])){
  // User Loged in
}
?>
```

Comment: Still not working, i wrote inside the if statement in php file echo "user is loged in"; but it never appear which mean the Sesson is always empty. And as you mention, first i visit opencart to start the session then i went to test.php @focus.style

Comment: 1. Insert this code in test.php just for test `<?php
session_start();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>`

Comment: 2. Clear Ocmod cache. *system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/common/header.php*. If you can see that file file there - remove it (it will appear again, cached by system)

Comment: Thank you very much brother now it works :)). After removing that cache file problem solved.